# Is this the best way to script my Kantu macro?

Tags: json, imacros, browser-automation

Using Kantu 2.5.2 on Chrome Version 64.0.3282.186

My script needs to do this for me:
1. Push the search button on the page
2. if something pops up, Click button A, B, then C.

It does this on a constant loop until A B and C pop up.

This is my script:

```html
{
  "CreationDate": "2018-2-26",
  "Commands": [
    {
      "Command": "click",
      "Target": "id=btnSearchTrade",
      "Value": ""
    },
    {
      "Command": "waitForPageToLoad",
      "Target": "",
      "Value": ""
    },
    {
      "Command": "store",
      "Target": "true",
      "Value": "!Errorignore"
    },
    {
      "Command": "click",
      "Target": "id=UPDOWN1013612",
      "Value": ""
    },
    {
      "Command": "click",
      "Target": "id=btnCreatePickup",
      "Value": ""
    },
    {
      "Command": "click",
      "Target": "/html/body/div[8]/div[3]/div/button[1]/span",
      "Value": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

The problem:  Kantu gets very slow after it goes through this about 5 times.  It should only take about 2 seconds each step but ends up taking 30 seconds per step and just gets even more slow each time.

Is there a better way I can script this in Kantu?  I don't think I can use if/then logic with the free version.

Answer (score 0):

Try update to the latest version.

You should be able to accomplish this with a combination of if/else, [while](https://ui.vision/docs/selenium-ide/while) and [pause](https://ui.vision/docs/selenium-ide/pause).